# how do I trigger the click event on AVRoutePickerView using swift

Tags: ios, swift, airplay

Using AVRoutePickerView, I'm able to do the Airplay programmatically upon tapping the Airplay icon.
Now I want, on viewDidLoad it should initialize the AVRoutePickerView and even tap the airplay icon (no need to manually tap on icon).

Here's my small piece of code to display Airplay icon on UIView

> let routePV = AVRoutePickerView(frame: CGRect(x: 30.0, y: 150.0,
>   width: 30.0, height: 30.0))
>             routePV = UIColor.clear
>   self.view.addSubview(routePV)

I'm really not sure how to trigger tap on viewdidload ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

This is possible. However I must caution it is likely to be quite unexpected behavior to present this interface without user interaction. I’d recommend only doing this as a direct result of the user intending to present this interface.

Make sure you have added it to your view hierarchy.

```
let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView()
view.addSubview(routePickerView)
```

If desired, you can hide it.

```
routePickerView.isHidden = true
```

Then to present the route picker interface, trigger `touchUpInside` on its `UIButton`:

```
if let routePickerButton = routePickerView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) as? UIButton {
    routePickerButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Do note that this could stop working in a future iOS release.

Comment: could you please tell me why it will not work on future release because I am implementing AirPlay. Thanks!

Comment: @YogeshPatel It might stop working because it’s a bit of a hack to find the button and manually trigger it

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just added a question regarding this topic. Could you please check and answer that if possible. Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481231/how-to-add-an-airplay-button-to-an-app-in-swift-5

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use an extension:

```
fileprivate extension AVRoutePickerView {
    func present() {
        let routePickerButton = subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIButton }) as? UIButton
        routePickerButton?.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

Example implementation:

```
class RandomViewController: UIViewController {

    ...

    private lazy var routePickerView = { 
        let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: .zero)
        routePickerView.isHidden = true
        view.addSubview(routePickerView)
        return routePickerView
    }

    ...

    @IBAction func presentPickerView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        routePickerView.present()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The above snippet worked for me.
But `routePickerView.present()` gives error.
If you get an error, replace it with `routePickerView().present()`

thanks.

Comment: This should be a comment. On StackOverflow, an "Answer" is a solution for the original question.Also keep in mind that the order of answers may change according to user setting and answer score, so better than writing "The above snippet..." is something like "... in @Stefan's answer..." if you need to another answer.

Comment: @soundflix You must have 50 comments to comment. But other people may have had the same problem as me. That's why I wrote it as an answer. Thank you.