# How to Add an AirPlay button to an app in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, swift5, airplay

I want to implement an Airplay button that shows the Bluetooth, iPhone option like in the iPhone music app we click on Airplay. I did some of the code but I am facing some issues.

1. As I implement, MPVolumeView works fine but unable to change the button colour. I checked with tint colour but not working
2. Added code of AVRoutePickerView it's not working It does not trigger so It not display that AirPlay Popup view
3. I want to show this Airplay Popup View when clicking on UIButton but I can't find any solution regards this so I take UIView for it.

There are some links SO that work for some of the points but not for the whole thing

[AirPlay button on custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311373/airplay-button-on-custom-view)

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/ios-add-an-airplay-button-to-an-app

[iOS - How can I display an 'AirPlay' popup menu in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879210/ios-how-can-i-display-an-airplay-popup-menu-in-swift)

Please check the below Screenshot for more information.

[image]

Please check the code

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

class TempDemoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var airPlayView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupAirPlayButton()
    }
    
    func setupAirPlayButton() {
        var buttonView: UIView = UIView()
        let buttonFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
                
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            let routerPickerView = AVRoutePickerView(frame: buttonFrame)
            buttonView.addSubview(routerPickerView)
            
            routerPickerView.tintColor = UIColor(named: "PrimaryColor")
            routerPickerView.activeTintColor = .white
            routerPickerView.prioritizesVideoDevices = true
        }else{
            let airplayButton = MPVolumeView(frame: buttonFrame)
            airplayButton.showsVolumeSlider = false
            buttonView = airplayButton
        }
        airPlayView.addSubview(buttonView)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     setAirplayButton()
  } 
    
 func setAirplayButton(){
    let buttonView  = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    let routerPickerView =  AVRoutePickerView(frame: buttonView.bounds)       
     routerPickerView.tintColor = UIColor.green
     routerPickerView.activeTintColor = .white
     buttonView.addSubview(routerPickerView)
     self.airPlayView.addSubview(buttonView)
  }
```

**Note** : airPlayView is UIView that i added in storyboard.

Comment: Please add more detail on your answer so OP and other users can able to get it like how and where they need to write the above code and all.